# JavaFX switching fxml files: Exception in thread ... InvocationTargetException

Tags: nullpointerexception, fxml, runtimeexception, invocationtargetexception

I have a JavaFX application in which the user presses a button, which loads a new fxml.  This works fine.  However, when I created another button on the second fxml to bring the user to the third fxml, I get the following output in console.  Sorry for putting so much code below, I didn't know what would be important or not.  Any ideas?  It says there is a nullpointer, but I know that the file path for productivitySlider.fxml is correct.  Thanks for any help.

```
Jan 13, 2019 4:15:52 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 10.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.191
Jan 13, 2019 4:15:55 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 10.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.191
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at application.comfortControl.loadProductivity(comfortControl.java:26)
    ... 55 more
```

## Here is my main java file:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {

            // Load FXML file
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("HumansightFirstDraft.fxml"));

            // Create scene
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 600);

            //Load CSS
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());

            // Display application
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setResizable(false);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

## Here is the first and second fxml files, respectively (HumansightFirstDraft.fxml & comfortSlider.fxml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.Blend?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="rootPane" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="400.0" stylesheets="@application.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.HumansightFirstDraftControl">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="startSurvey" layoutX="135.0" layoutY="500.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#loadComfort" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="130.0" text="Daily Survey" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="Oxygen" size="18.0" />
         </font>
         <effect>
            <Blend />
         </effect>
      </Button>
      <Label alignment="CENTER" focusTraversable="false" layoutX="60.0" layoutY="320.0" mouseTransparent="true" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="300.0" text="text1" wrapText="true">
         <font>
            <Font name="Oxygen" size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Slider?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.Blend?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="600.0" maxWidth="400.0" minHeight="600.0" minWidth="400.0" prefHeight="600" prefWidth="400" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.comfortControl">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="70.0" layoutY="377.0" text="text2">
         <font>
            <Font name="Oxygen" size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <ImageView fitHeight="61.0" fitWidth="346.0" layoutX="32.0" layoutY="415.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" style="-fx-scale-y: 1.4;">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../bin/application/sliderColors.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Slider fx:id="comfortSlider" layoutX="36.0" layoutY="424.0" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="329.0">
         <effect>
            <Blend />
         </effect>
      </Slider>
      <Button fx:id="toProductivity" layoutX="135.0" layoutY="500.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#loadProductivity" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="130.0" stylesheets="@application.css" text="Next" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="Oxygen" size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

## Here are the first and second controller java files, respectively:

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class HumansightFirstDraftControl implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane rootPane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @FXML
    private void loadComfort(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        AnchorPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/comfortSlider.fxml"));
        rootPane.getChildren().setAll(pane);
    }

}
```

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class comfortControl implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane rootPane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @FXML
    private void loadProductivity(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        AnchorPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/productivitySlider.fxml"));
        rootPane.getChildren().setAll(pane);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, it was a silly mistake, but I'll post my solution on the off chance that someone is as stupid as me.  All I had to do was change the fx:id and the anchorPane names to more specific names for each.  I named both anchorPanes rootPanes, so it was all funky.